# Comforting/encouraging English idiom meaning 'it's not that bad'/'it's not all bad'

Tags: phrases, idioms

I have been told this by an unknown man on the street a few years ago, when I was looking particularly sad.

It was something that meant to say 'it's not all bad, cheer up', and it either contained the word 'sea' or another word from the lexical field of sea/sea navigation. 
I just can't remember it right now. 
Thanks!

Comment: Something like "there are plenty of fish in the sea"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [encapsulating a positive thing among many negative things](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/132818/encapsulating-a-positive-thing-among-many-negative-things)

Comment: @Lawrence - good one, you should post it.  I know it as *There are plenty of **other** fish in the sea* (i.e. you may have lost your love, but there are lots more to be found).

Comment: "After the storm comes the calm" ?

Comment: @Dan Done. Yes, the version with "other" is also idiomatic.

Answer (score 3):

In the context of rejection, a well-known saying is:

> **There are plenty of [other] fish in the sea.**
>   Meaning: there are many more potential opportunities available.
>   [- wikipedia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/there_are_plenty_of_fish_in_the_sea)

Answer (score 2):

The expression I remember is

> *There are worse things at sea.*

but [UsingEnglish.com](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/worse+things+happen+at+sea.html) renders it:

> *Worse things happen at sea.*
>
> This idiomatic expression is used as a way of telling someone not to
>   worry so much about their problems [put them in perspective].

Comment: I know/use only the *second* of your versions.

Comment: But there are quite a few Google hits for the first.

Comment: And they are subtly different: The first warns of the hostile nature of the sea (storms, monsters, the Unknown...), while the second hints at the awful things people can do to each other under pressure.